# awk grabbing last entry and all data until the end of a file ( including null )

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, sh

I'm using awk to read a file and grab everything from the last entry until the end of the file.

```
awk '/^[(]/{s="";} {s=s"\n"$0;} END{print substr(s,2);}' file_one > file_two
```

The problem I'm having is that when the entry has NULL values it only returns `(`. Is there a flag to grab even the null data until the end of the file? How can I accurately get that data?

[image]

Comment: @john1024 any thoughts?

Comment: @anubhava that image that is attached is sample input. It's the bottom of the file. The output would be just the (data to the end of the file in file_two

Comment: Sorry awk command cannot work with images. You should provide text data.

Comment: @anubhava well, I can't post null here. I could post a hex dump, but that may not help you

Comment: can you use `strings file_one |tail -1` or make a script using `od`?

Comment: awk work with text data, not binary data.  One way is to translate to text version (hexedump, ...) treat the condition (so `(` is now certainly into another format) and translate it back or use tools that work with binary value (ex: http://linux.die.net/man/1/uni2ascii)

Comment: mawk and GNU awk have BINMODE for handling binary data, you probably want `awk -v BINMODE=3 '<script>' file`. See the man page for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use perl for this:

1. create a file with nulls

   ```
   $ printf '}if\n\n(\0\0\0hello world\0\nfoo\nbar\n' > file
   $ od -c file
   0000000   }   i   f  \n  \n   (  \0  \0  \0   h   e   l   l   o       w
   0000020   o   r   l   d  \0  \n   f   o   o  \n   b   a   r  \n
   0000036
   ```
2. extract the stuff after the last `(`

   ```
   $ perl -0777 -F'\(' -ane 'print $F[-1]' file
   hello world
   foo
   bar
   $ perl -0777 -F'\(' -ane 'print $F[-1]' file | od -c
   0000000  \0  \0  \0   h   e   l   l   o       w   o   r   l   d  \0  \n
   0000020   f   o   o  \n   b   a   r  \n
   0000030
   ```

Notes

- the options `-0777 -n` will read the whole file into a single string
- the options `-F'\(' -a` will split the string into the array `@F` using `(` as the delimiter
- `$F[-1]` is the last element of the array.